# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps inconsistent warning when object destructuring

Tags: react-hooks

I use the `useHistory` hook but I am receiving the exhaustive-deps warning when I don't destructure the object.

```
const history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
  history.replace({ search: '' });
}, [history.replace]);

const change = useCallback(() => {
  history.replace({ search: '' });
}, [history.replace]);
```

I receive the following warning:

> React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'history'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

But, if I do something like this, it works:

```
const { replace } = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
  replace({ search: '' });
}, [replace]);

const change = useCallback(() => {
  replace({ search: '' });
}, [replace]);
```

Comment: useHistory could be hook made by ufo please specify the hook is it react router or what ?

Comment: your replace var has an issue it wont trigger the callback for some reason

Comment: @stop-error any hook that returns a function has this behavior, it could be a custom hook or any library